# Print a c# object list

Tags: c#, hubspot

I am using this wrapper for hubspot apis : https://github.com/squaredup/HubSpot.NET

And I can modify data and make calls, but when I retrieve info I have no idea how to print it to the console. This is my code :

```
var companies = api.Company.List<CompanyHubSpotModel>(
                 new ListRequestOptions { Limit = 10 });

foreach (CompanyListHubSpotModel company in companies) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(company.ToString());
}
```

I get the following error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'CompanyListHubSpotModel' because 'CompanyListHubSpotModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

I tried adding an enum to the CompanyHubspot class and to the ListHubSpot class but it still tells me that enum is not defined how can I print this list of objects?

Comment: Most likely `CompanyListHubSpotModel` isn't an enumerable.

Comment: So how do I iterate through it to print it?

Answer (score 0):

CompanyListHubSpotModel has a property called "Companies" of type IList.

Change your code to this:

```
var companiesList = api.Company.List<CompanyHubSpotModel>(
                 new ListRequestOptions { Limit = 10 });

foreach (CompanyHubSpotModel company in companiesList.Companies) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(company.ToString());
}
```

https://github.com/squaredup/HubSpot.NET/blob/master/HubSpot.NET/Api/Company/Dto/CompanyListHubSpotModel.cs